Query performance issue when adding UNION to CTE/Query
I have the below CTE/Query running on Oracle database.
WITH Txn_Cost as
(SELECT * FROM 
                 (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                          ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                          TO_CHAR(A.REC_TRXN_ID) REC_TRXN_ID,
                          TO_CHAR(B.TRANSACTION_ID) TRANSACTION_ID,
                          TO_CHAR(B.COST_DATE) COST_DATE,
                          TO_CHAR(A.QUANTITY_ONHAND) QUANTITY_ONHAND,
                          B.TRANSACTION_COST
                      FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                           CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                           CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                     WHERE 1=1
                       AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                       AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
                   
                       AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                       AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                       AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                       --AND B.COST_DATE=(SELECT MAX(COST_DATE) FROM CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B_COST WHERE 
                       --B_COST.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                       --TRANSACTION_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
                       --)
                     --  AND B.TRANSACTION_ID = C.TRANSACTION_ID
                       AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID
                    --AND C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = IOQD.secondary_inventory     
    ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
    )
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1    

)
        
Select * from 
(( 
SELECT item_number,item_DESCRIPTION   
      ,decode(substr(subinventory_code,1,3),'11C','11CCL'
              ,'11O','11OPR'
              ,'18O','18OPR'
              ,'41S','24000'
              ,'41O','41OPR'
              ,'60O','60OPR'
              ,'70O','70OPR'
              ,'70C','70CCL'
              ,subinventory_code
             ) subinventory_code
      ,p_inv,
       round(Cost,5) Cost,Patient_Chargeable,Chargeable_code,
       patient_charges,STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG,INV_LOCATOR ,rownum ivt_seqnum 
       ,               CONSIGNED_FLAG
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ESI.item_number,
                replace(replace(ESI.LONG_DESCRIPTION,chr(10)),chr(13))                  item_DESCRIPTION,
                IOQD.subinventory_code,
                IOQD.inventory_item_id                 p_inv,
                TC.TRANSACTION_COST   Cost,
                ESI.attribute5
                Patient_Chargeable,
                ESI.attribute2
                Chargeable_code,
                ESI.attribute3
                patient_charges,
                ESI.STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG,
(select SEGMENT1||'-'||SEGMENT2||'-'||SEGMENT3||'-'||SEGMENT4||'-'||SEGMENT5
                   from inv_item_locations
                  where inventory_location_id= ioqd.locator_id and length(Segment1) < 3
and length(Segment1) >= 1
                ) INV_LOCATOR,
        CASE WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
                           WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '2' THEN 'N'
                          END AS CONSIGNED_FLAG
FROM   inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD,
       egp_system_items ESI, 
       Txn_Cost TC
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
       AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
       AND ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num
        AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.subinventory_code
       AND IOQD.subinventory_code IN (select distinct SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME from inv_secondary_inventories where attribute1='Y'  ))
)  --)

UNION ALL

(SELECT DISTINCT ESI.item_number,
                replace(replace(ESI.LONG_DESCRIPTION,chr(10)),chr(13))                  item_DESCRIPTION
--                IOQD.secondary_inventory subinventory_code,
,decode(substr(IOQD.secondary_inventory,1,3),'11C','11CCL'
              ,'11O','11OPR'
              ,'18O','18OPR'
              ,'41S','24000'
              ,'41O','41OPR'
              ,'60O','60OPR'
              ,'70O','70OPR'
              ,'70C','70CCL'
              ,IOQD.secondary_inventory
             ) subinventory_code,
                IOQD.inventory_item_id
                p_inv,
                TC.TRANSACTION_COST   Cost,
                ESI.attribute5
                Patient_Chargeable,
                ESI.attribute2
                Chargeable_code,
                ESI.attribute3
                patient_charges,
                ESI.STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG,
case when 
 (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )   

when (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_secondary_locators iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.SECONDARY_LOCATOR= iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum = 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
        Then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_secondary_locators iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.SECONDARY_LOCATOR= iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum = 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )

Else 'AAAAAAA'
END as      INV_LOCATOR, 
 rownum ivt_seqnum
        , CASE WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
                           WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '2' THEN 'N'
                          END AS CONSIGNED_FLAG

FROM   INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES IOQD,
       egp_system_items ESI,
       Txn_Cost TC
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
       AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
       AND ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num
       AND IOQD.secondary_inventory IN (select distinct SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME from inv_secondary_inventories where attribute1='Y')
       AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                         FROM inv_onhand_quantities_detail
                        WHERE subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
                          AND inventory_item_id  = ESI.inventory_item_id
                      ) 
      AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.secondary_inventory

) )results 

order by subinventory_code, INV_LOCATOR

The above runs in an acceptable amount of time, however when I add this bit of code below it takes significantly longer. Below is the exact code added, and then (below that) I have it incorporated into the entire query as well.
    UNION 
          SELECT ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,              
                SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                round((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),3) TRANSACTION_COST 
            FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
               ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC
                 ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
                ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
                ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM
                ,EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM           
                             
            WHERE SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
             AND SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
             AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
              AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
              AND (LN.EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL OR LN.EXPIRATION_DATE > sysdate)
              AND LN.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELED'
              AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
              AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
              AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
              AND UOM.UOM_CODE = LN.UOM_CODE
              AND ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
              AND ITM.organization_id = 300000526890796
              AND SUBSTR(SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME,1,2) = '70'
              AND ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num  

Entire Query with the above section added that is causing performance issue:
WITH Txn_Cost as
    (SELECT * FROM 
                     (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                              ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                              TO_CHAR(A.REC_TRXN_ID) REC_TRXN_ID,
                              TO_CHAR(B.TRANSACTION_ID) TRANSACTION_ID,
                              TO_CHAR(B.COST_DATE) COST_DATE,
                              TO_CHAR(A.QUANTITY_ONHAND) QUANTITY_ONHAND,
                              B.TRANSACTION_COST
                          FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                               CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                               CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                         WHERE 1=1
                           AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                           AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
                       
                           AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                           AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                           AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                           --AND B.COST_DATE=(SELECT MAX(COST_DATE) FROM CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B_COST WHERE 
                           --B_COST.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                           --TRANSACTION_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
                           --)
                         --  AND B.TRANSACTION_ID = C.TRANSACTION_ID
                           AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID
                        --AND C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = IOQD.secondary_inventory     
        ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
        )
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1
 --BEGIN CODE CHANGES!!!!-----------------------------------   
    UNION 
      SELECT ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,              
            SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            round((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),3) TRANSACTION_COST 
        FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
           ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC
             ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
            ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
            ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM
            ,EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM                   
                                     
        
         WHERE SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
         AND SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
         AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
          AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
          AND (LN.EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL OR LN.EXPIRATION_DATE > sysdate)
          AND LN.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELED'
          AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
          AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
          AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
          AND UOM.UOM_CODE = LN.UOM_CODE
          AND ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
          AND ITM.organization_id = 300000526890796
          AND SUBSTR(SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME,1,2) = '70'
          AND ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num  
    --END CODE CHANGES!!!!----------------------------------- 
    )
                   
    
    Select * from 
    (( 
    SELECT item_number,item_DESCRIPTION       
          ,decode(substr(subinventory_code,1,3),'11C','11CCL'
                  ,'11O','11OPR'
                  ,'18O','18OPR'
                  ,'41S','24000'
                  ,'41O','41OPR'
                  ,'60O','60OPR'
                  ,'70O','70OPR'
                  ,'70C','70CCL'
                  ,subinventory_code
                 ) subinventory_code
          ,p_inv,
           round(Cost,5) Cost,Patient_Chargeable,Chargeable_code,
           patient_charges,STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG,INV_LOCATOR ,rownum ivt_seqnum 
           ,               CONSIGNED_FLAG
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ESI.item_number,
                    replace(replace(ESI.LONG_DESCRIPTION,chr(10)),chr(13))                  item_DESCRIPTION,
                    IOQD.subinventory_code,
                    IOQD.inventory_item_id                 p_inv,
                    TC.TRANSACTION_COST   Cost,
                    ESI.attribute5
                    Patient_Chargeable,
                    ESI.attribute2
                    Chargeable_code,
                    ESI.attribute3
                    patient_charges,
                    ESI.STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG,
    (select SEGMENT1||'-'||SEGMENT2||'-'||SEGMENT3||'-'||SEGMENT4||'-'||SEGMENT5
                       from inv_item_locations
                      where inventory_location_id= ioqd.locator_id and length(Segment1) < 3
    and length(Segment1) >= 1
                    ) INV_LOCATOR,
            CASE WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
                               WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '2' THEN 'N'
                              END AS CONSIGNED_FLAG
    FROM   inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD,
           egp_system_items ESI, 
           Txn_Cost TC
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
           AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
           AND ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num
            AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.subinventory_code
           AND IOQD.subinventory_code IN (select distinct SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME from inv_secondary_inventories where attribute1='Y'  ))
    )  --)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    (SELECT DISTINCT ESI.item_number,
                    replace(replace(ESI.LONG_DESCRIPTION,chr(10)),chr(13))                  item_DESCRIPTION
    --                IOQD.secondary_inventory subinventory_code,
    ,decode(substr(IOQD.secondary_inventory,1,3),'11C','11CCL'
                  ,'11O','11OPR'
                  ,'18O','18OPR'
                  ,'41S','24000'
                  ,'41O','41OPR'
                  ,'60O','60OPR'
                  ,'70O','70OPR'
                  ,'70C','70CCL'
                  ,IOQD.secondary_inventory
                 ) subinventory_code,
                    IOQD.inventory_item_id
                    p_inv,
                    TC.TRANSACTION_COST   Cost,
                    ESI.attribute5
                    Patient_Chargeable,
                    ESI.attribute2
                    Chargeable_code,
                    ESI.attribute3
                    patient_charges,
                    ESI.STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG,
    case when 
     (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
               FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                    inv_item_locations iil
              WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
                AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
                AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
                AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
    then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
               FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                    inv_item_locations iil
              WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
                AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
                AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
                AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )   
    
    when (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
               FROM inv_secondary_locators iild, 
                    inv_item_locations iil
              WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
                AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
                AND iild.SECONDARY_LOCATOR= iil.inventory_location_id
                AND rownum = 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
            Then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
               FROM inv_secondary_locators iild, 
                    inv_item_locations iil
              WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
                AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
                AND iild.SECONDARY_LOCATOR= iil.inventory_location_id
                AND rownum = 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )
    
    Else 'AAAAAAA'
    END as      INV_LOCATOR, 
     rownum ivt_seqnum
            , CASE WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '1' THEN 'Y'
                               WHEN ESI.CONSIGNED_FLAG = '2' THEN 'N'
                              END AS CONSIGNED_FLAG
    
    FROM   INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES IOQD,
           egp_system_items ESI,
           Txn_Cost TC
    WHERE  1 = 1
           AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
           AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
           AND ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num
           AND IOQD.secondary_inventory IN (select distinct SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME from inv_secondary_inventories where attribute1='Y')
           AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                             FROM inv_onhand_quantities_detail
                            WHERE subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
                              AND inventory_item_id  = ESI.inventory_item_id
                          ) 
          AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.secondary_inventory
    --Order by addition 
    ) )results 
    
    order by subinventory_code, INV_LOCATOR

I did change some of the Subqueries in the WHERE clause to be fully joined tables, and also re-worked the INV_LOCATOR CASE statements but that did not improve performance. I am looking for assistance in how I can improve performance from the section of code I added. Thank you.
EDIT:
Generated Explain Plan from modified query (link): https://pastebin.com/x7Rm0jmF

you use Union in once place and UNION ALL in another.  Should the added union be a union all to avoid the distinct a UNION does?

@xQbert I added 'UNION ALL' to the new block of code, but it doesn't appear to have much affect on performance.

You seem to be dealing with a query of which at least parts were written a long time ago (1980s or 1990s, I suppose from the out-dated join syntax and those many all upper case parts). As you are already working at it, you should write it anew (from scratch). Thus you may already fix some weaknesses. Then, SELECT DISTINCT is almost always an indicator for a badly written query (sometimes even a bad data model). UNION instead of UNION ALL is often just a mistake giving the DBMS more work to do than need be.

Have you looked at any explain plans? These help identify performance issues. What is the performance of the added part is run by itself?

Prior to the change the CTE "Txn_Cost " can only have 1 row. After the change that CTE can have multiple rows. So when you join that modified CTE into the subsequent (very ugly) query you will possibly multiply the number of total rows the main query has to deal with, and that contributes to your performance issues. Please do learn how to use modern ANSI join syntax (i.e. stop using commas in the FROM clause)

@AdrianMaxwell Please see my comments under your proposed answer below. Thank you for any assistance!

The Note in the explain plan that says "dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)", which implies that at least one of the tables is missing optimizer statistics. You might also want to consider generating an execution plan with actual numbers, instead of an explain plan with guesses. Possibly only one of the 277 operations is slow and needs tuning, but we don't know which one. I recommend you generate a SQL Monitoring report by running the statement again and then running select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('your SQL_ID') from dual;

Here's a re-write example employing more recent join syntax. Note I have retained some conditions in the where clause but many of those could also be used to qualify the joins, which I display later:
Note that if this CTE produces several rows, then in your original query, whenever you join "Txn_Cost" you will multiply the number of rows that the larger query must deal with (and reduce to distinct rows).
WITH Txn_Cost
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
              A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
            , B.TRANSACTION_COST
        FROM CST_ONHAND_V A
        INNER JOIN CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B ON A.REC_TRXN_ID = B.TRANSACTION_ID
            AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
            AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
            AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
        INNER JOIN CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C ON A.REC_TRXN_ID = C.REC_TRXN_ID
        WHERE A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
        ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
        )
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    --BEGIN CODE CHANGES!!!!-----------------------------------   

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
        , round((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE), 3) TRANSACTION_COST
    FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
    INNER JOIN inv_secondary_inventories SEC ON SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
        AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
    INNER JOIN PO_LINES_ALL LN ON LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR ON HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
    INNER JOIN INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM ON UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
        AND UOM.UOM_CODE = LN.UOM_CODE
    INNER JOIN EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM ON ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    WHERE ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
        AND ITM.organization_id = 300000526890796
        AND SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
        AND SUBSTR(SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME, 1, 2) = '70'
        AND (
            LN.EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL
            OR LN.EXPIRATION_DATE > sysdate
            )
        AND LN.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELED'
        AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
    )
SELECT *
FROM Txn_Cost

You can also move many of the where clause predicates into joins e.g.
INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR ON HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
    AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'

nb: This is more useful and important if using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

I appreciate your feedback, however there are some syntax issues with the query you proposed above (mainly in the joins). Also you removed some of the Columns I was originally selecting from in the CTE that I need to join on the larger query (i.e. SUBINVENTORY_CODE. Yes the CTE is/can fetching multiple rows, so I think that is somehow impacting performance of the overall query. When I run the CTE by itself separately it runs quickly, and Vice versa if I run the entire query without the UNION ALL block added to the CTE it runs satisfactorily.

Please add JOIN on line #13 and remove AND on line #30  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/6i5a5RSz for linenumbers)

thanks @Luuk line 13 corrected, but line 30 does not need AND (it is the ON condition) so the line break is removed instead see https://dbfiddle.uk/D5ytk1MA`

@Nick as mentioned because the new part of the CTE adds rows, this will then MULTIPLY the rows in subsequent queries once joined - than you ask those subsequent queries to reduce the rows via distinct or union. i.e. you make more work for the subsequent query.

@AdrianMaxwell what would be your suggestion to optimize that then? I did notice if I add the two queries in the CTE directly to the main query as a subqueried-table that it runs significantly faster...

I would recommend use of explain plans, this is the primary tool for performance tuning. I would also just rebuild the query aiming to achieve substantial simplification.
